# I have a balanced dataset, after I split it to train & test set, the test set is imbalance, what is the reason?

Tags: python, split, classification

My whole dataset is 8 classes, 100 subjects for each class.
When I do the classification, I split it, the test set is imbalance.

I do split:

```
_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data.iloc[:, :-1], data.iloc[:, -1], test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
```

The confusion matrix of RFC is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Yve2.png)
eg: There's only 10 from the second class, why and should I balance it?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

The `train_test_split` function from scikit-learn splits classes number in random fashion.

To keep the number of classes equal in the test and train set you need to add the "stratify" argument.

[See documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)

```py
_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data.iloc[:, :-1], 
    data.iloc[:, -1], 
    test_size=0.2, 
    random_state=42,
    stratify=data.iloc[:, -1])
```